# WP Rest get all by post within that category, by category name not by cat ID

Tags: wp-api

I'm trying to display all posts within a specific category but by slug name not by cat id, below is what I've tried.

> http://centreformemories.org/blog//wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[taxonomy]=category&filter[term]=test

but seems its not working at all like it returns all the posts instead and not filtered by category (per slug name). Any help, ideas please?